# Combinations and the sequencing of DNA

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

> There are four different nucleotides in DNA, from a mathematical point
>   of view, DNA sequences can be represented by words over the four
>   letters alphabet $A = \{A, C, G, T\}$.
>
> (a) If you could write one sequences a second, how long will it take
>   you to write all DNA sequences of size 12? Give your answer in the
>   format (hours, minutes, seconds).
>
> (b) Of all the DNA sequences of size 12, in how many of them do we see
>   both the sequences $ACGTATA$ and $TATAC$? We say that $ACGTATA$ and
>   $TATAC$ are subsequences.

My solution for part a:

$hours = \frac{\frac{12!}{60}}{60} $

My solution for part b:

Put side by side,
$ACGTATA$ and $TATAC$  
could be solved in two ways; 
$ACGTATA$$TATAC$ and $TATAC$$ACGTATA$

when $TATACGTATA$ is the sequence there are 2 free spaces for DNA nucleotides. So this may be done in $(4*4)(4*4)(4*4)(4*4) = 4096$ ways.

when $ACGTATAC$ is the sequence there are 4 free spaces for DNA nucleotides. So this may be done in $(4*4*4)(4*4*4)(4*4*4)(4*4*4)(4*4*4) = 16777216$ ways.

Please let my know whether or not my solution to the problem is correct. Please correct any mistakes I have made. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: $12!$ is wrong -- that is the number of ways to rearrange 12 different distinguishable objects, not the number of ways to select one of four letters in each of the 12 positions. (It should make you suspicious already that $12!$ does not seem to take into account at all how many bases you have to choose from).

Comment: I can't follow your reasoning in part (b) at all -- your expressions don't make sense, and the computations don't match your expressions anyway. For example, $(4\times 4)(4\times 4)(4\times 4)(4\times 4)$ is 65536, not 4096.

Comment: And you're not accounting for the possibility of `ACGTATATAC`...

Comment: @Miroslav I completed my answer. If you have questions, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

(a) You can choose one of four letters at 12 positions, which gives $4^{12}$ possible sequences of length 12.

At one sequence per second, it takes $(4660 \mbox{h}, 20\mbox{m}, 16 \mbox{s})$

(b) We have these cases:

- $ACGTATA \cdot TATAC$, contributing $1$ word
- $TATAC \cdot ACGTATA$, contributing $1$ word
- $u \cdot ACGTATA \cdot TAC \cdot v$, with $\lvert uv \rvert = 2$, contributing $3\times 4^2 = 48$ words
- $u \cdot ACGTATA \cdot C \cdot v$, with $\lvert uv \rvert = 4$, contributing $5 \times 4^4 = 1280$ words
- $u \cdot TAT \cdot ACGTATA \cdot v$, with $\lvert uv \rvert = 2$, contributing $3\times 4^2 = 48$ words

Where $\cdot$ is the concatenation operator (which like the multiplication can be omitted) and $u, v \in \{ A, C, G, T \}^*$ (finite DNA sequences, including the empty sequence).

The factors result from the choices to split a word $w$ into two substrings $w = u \cdot v$.

This gives $1+1+48+1280+48= 1378$ words.

However my friend Ruby thinks these are only $1370$ words, so we need to eliminate some multiple countings.

[Asked about](https://gist.github.com/140bb968addb7a47ab48) which words are counted more than once and why, [she told me](https://gist.github.com/7d37e280b099213d1667):

```
517: ATATACGTATAC [4] [5]
788: CTATACGTATAC [4] [5]
1059: GTATACGTATAC [4] [5]
1202: TATACGTATACA [4] [5]
1203: TATACGTATACC [4] [5]
1204: TATACGTATACG [4] [5]
1205: TATACGTATACT [4] [5]
1343: TTATACGTATAC [4] [5]
```

These are the sequences $u \cdot TAT \cdot ACGTATA \cdot C \cdot v$ with $\lvert uv \rvert = 1$, contributing $2 \times 4^1 = 8$ words. This is the intersection of the fourth and fifth case above.